# How to deal with skipping segments in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube-dl

I wanted to download 2 minutes from a live stream of youtube. So, I run the following cmd but the problem is that ffmpeg throws me `skipping X segments ahead, expired from playlists` and the output video freezes several times. I added the command and the output:

[cmd+output](https://ctrlv.it/id/107124/1728131188)

You can see four or five times skipping segments. Anyone knows how to fix this?? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The warning is not coming from FFmpeg, but youtube-dl.

youtube-dl has an `is_live` flag, so give that a shot:

```
ffmpeg -i $(youtube-dl -o is_live -f 95 -g https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0R0T0mQmx7I) -c copy -t 00:02:00 output.mp4
```

If that doesn't work out, you can try dealing with it in FFmpeg by having the input be your screen. I can imagine how taxing this can be on a system, so perhaps dropping your display resolution would help if the system struggles.

Example:

> ffmpeg -f gdigrab -i desktop -c libx264 output.mp4

I'm not sure how to capture the audio. I think you would have to run a cable from your output to line in, and then find the device name to update your command:

- Get name of line-in device: `ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy`
- Add it to your command: `ffmpeg -f gdigrab -i desktop -f dshow -i -c libx264 -i audio="LINE IN DEVICE NAME" output.mp4`

Comment: It doesn't work. The first option still throws `skipping segments`. And the second command throws `Unknown input format: 'dshow'`... Perhaps It related with version of ffmpeg 3.4 and gcc 5.4 ?

Comment: Looks like I wrote the wrong command, I updated it with one that should work.

Comment: Anyone could help?

Comment: Did the new example not work?

Comment: I could record from my desktop but the audio is mandatory. Also I need the video as it is and I don't want to do another video edition. Moreover, It must be a simple solution! Another idea?

Comment: With FFmpeg? No... nothing comes to mind.